# Error 500 calling a WebService from c#

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to make a SOAP request from a C# app to a PHP webservice and I always get error 500. Trying via SoapUI results the same error.

The only way I could find to make it work was calling the WS from a PHP application.

This is my Soap Envelope

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:main">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:addTicketByData soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <auth xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[$1$fC5.505.$ury..6xkf9eb/TUEgKdqF/]]></auth>
         <xmlValue xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[ 
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
            <wsqualitor>
                <contents>
                    <data>
                        <cdcliente>1</cdcliente>
                        <cdcontato>121</cdcontato>
                        <idchamado>1</idchamado> 
                        <cdtipochamado>17</cdtipochamado>
                        <cdcategoria>2325</cdcategoria>
                        <cdlocalidade>2</cdlocalidade> 
                        <cdseveridade>1</cdseveridade> 
                        <dschamado>Testando Web Service Qualitor</dschamado>
                    </data>
                </contents>
            </wsqualitor> ]]>
        </xmlValue>
      </urn:addTicketByData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
      <title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         <!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}-->
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>Server Error</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
         <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
               <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
               <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What logs do you mean?

Comment: your server should most likely give you access to any logs. I can't tell you where they are because I don't know how your server is setup. It's up to you to find out where they are. Or, use error reporting to show it on screen. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The problem is: The webservice is not mine...

Comment: error reporting may help http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had an answer.

My provider was throwing Error 500 for all exceptions. So I couldn't figure out what was wrong. Talking to them I found out that I just needed to Allow Cookies on my binding. Worked fine.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="serverBinding" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO (In My Opinion), if the request send ny SOAP UI fails :

- the soap request send by Soap UI is well formated (i never had issues with it for years)
- the error come from the webservices called that doesn't undertsand the request

As said by Fred, contact the WebService supplier and ask him to look at his log.

It's maybe only a Web Server issue ?